Cannot kill suspended devenv.exe
I've started to get "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open" a way too often during the recent period of time when using Visual Studio 2022 v.17.5.4 under MS Win 11 Pro (v, 23H2 Build 22631.3447). It looks like this is a suspended devenv.exe process, which locks a custom C# library DLL. AFAIHF. The issue appears when debugging a C# console app compiled in Debug mode under VS2022, which uses a DLL, which was originally compiled in Release mode. The debugged console app is stopped on breakpoint and the referenced custom library DLL project's compiled mode is changed to Debug and recompiled. Then when returning to the C# console app project, stopping debugging session and trying to recompile results in the "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open" issue.
Quitting both VS2022 sessions, restarting them in Admin mode, trying to clean solution, recompile/rebuild doesn't help. Using Sysinternals' Process Explorer to kill suspended devenv.exe doesn't help either (see enclosed screenshot). Only MS Window system rebooting helps.
Mentioned above "development workflow" doesn't look good, no doubts - when stopping a C# console debugging session, then changing the referenced C# library project compile mode into Debug, recompiling it and re-starting Console app debugging session then all works fine. But the issue "Unable to kill a suspended devenv.exe even when using Systinternals Process Explorer" is still open here, how it can be effectively solved?


This is a problem with windows 11. I had similar entry point to this error but after 2 days of trying to find whats wrong i am able to reproduce this problem with just notepad: 1. start notepad 2. try to open big file (500MB for example) 3. click fast on notepad until it stops responding 4. close -> you have new un-killable noetpad.exe
